# Replacing all primes with 0

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, conditional, prime-numbers

I am attempting to utilise the 
    `Condition`
function to replace all primes in the list by a `0`.

Here are my codes:

```
Range[2000] /. x_ /; x \[Element] Prime -> 0
```

But it isn't performing as it should and I am unable to conceive an alternative syntax.

Comment: `Range[2000] /. x_ /; PrimeQ[x] -> 0`

Comment: `Range[2000] /. x_?PrimeQ :> 0`also

Comment: That should be `Primes`, not `Prime`.  `Prime` is a function. `Primes` is a set.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you for the heads up.